# Get last column in Google Sheets API v4 in c#

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-sheets

I have seen many posts about finding the last row of a given column for Google Sheets API v4 in C#, but I can't seem to find anything about finding the last column of a given row. I didn't find any questions about this specifically - but if I'm mistaken please direct me to the right place.

In my sheet, I have headers for each column. Over time, I anticipate I will need to add or remove columns as needed - it would be great to not have to update my code every time this happens.

I'm at the beginning stages of writing my code that gathers my data from Google Sheets - but here is what I have so far. I know that I will need to change the way my variable "range" is written, just don't know what.

```
static void ReadEntries()
    {
        var range = $"{sheet}!A1:ET";
        var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(SpreadsheetId, range);
        var response = request.Execute();
        var values = response.Values;
        if(values != null && values.Count>0)
        {
            foreach (var row in values)
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}", row[0], row[1], row[2]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No data found.");
        }
    }
```

**EDIT: SOLVED**
I used the pseudo code provided by Nazi A for this. I was having issues with the `if(row[col])` piece with casting and other system exceptions. It turns out `foreach` allows for us to not have to check if that `row[col]` is in range. Below is my final code in case anyone needs it in the future. I plan to let column "ET" declared in `var range = $"{sheet}!A1:ET;` be big enough to accommodate any future columns being added to my spreadsheet. Thanks for your help!

```
static void ReadEntries()
        {
            
            var range = $"{sheet}!A1:ET";
            var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(SpreadsheetId, range);
            var response = request.Execute();
            var values = response.Values;
            int max = 0;
            int currMax;
            
            if (values != null && values.Count>0)
            {
                foreach(var row in values)
                {
                    currMax = 0;
                    foreach(var col in row)
                    {
                        currMax++;
                    }

                    if (max < currMax)
                    {
                        max = currMax;
                    }
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No data found.");
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(max);
        }
```

Comment: will you be able to port a working javascript code for your question to C# if needed?

Comment: @Nazi A not sure what you mean by that - sorry. I am not very familiar with javascript.

Comment: Kudos to you. You even provided a better answer which i wasn't able to think of right away. +1. Goodluck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, you need to have a nested loop to traverse all rows and columns in `values`.

I have tested this psuedo code and worked but since I have no any means to run a C# code, this is all I can give to you. This is a pseudo code that should be readable to you.

```
var max = 0;
foreach(var row in values){
  var currMax = 0;

  foreach(var col in row){
    if(row[col]){ // as long as data exists, currMax will increment
      currMax++;
      continue;
    }
    break; // stop loop if last cell being checked is empty
  }

  if(max < currMax){ // assign the largest currMax to max
    max = currMax;
  }
}
```

So in this psuedo code, `max` will contain the value of the largest column of all rows in the range. this code above should replace your `foreach` call

If you have any questions, feel free to clarify below.

Comment: thank you for your help - I edited my original post with my final code.

Comment: Very clever approach !